# Errata for Fulton's "Young tableaux"

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, young-tableaux, errata

Fulton's *Young tableaux* is one of the best texts on the subject, one which I
often recommend and cite for reference. Unlike Fulton/Lang and
[Fulton/Harris](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108886/erratum-for-fulton-and-harris),
it is neither an early-dawn draft nor a chatty informal introduction but aims
(and often succeeds) at giving a streamlined and readable presentation of the
subject. All the more I find it important to spot and correct the occasional
errors in it.

I used to think it had none, until I learned of three seriously broken
proofs in rapid succession:

**Serious errors:**

1. **page 97, proof of Lemma 5 (§ 7.4):** The number
   \begin{align*}
   n_{\lambda}  & =\left\vert \left\{  \left(  p_{1},q_{1},p_{2},q_{2}\right)
   \ :\ p_{i}\in R\left(  T\right)  ,\ q_{i}\in C\left(  T\right)  \right.
   \right.  \\
   & \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left.  \left.  p_{1}q_{1}p_{2}q_{2}=1,
   \ \operatorname*{sgn}\left(  q_{1}\right)  =\operatorname*{sgn}\left(
   q_{2}\right)  \right\}  \right\vert
   \end{align*}
   (where $R\left(  T\right)  $ is the row-fixing group and $C\left(  T\right)  $
   the column-fixing group of a given standard tableau $T$) is wrong, as it fails
   to satisfy the equation $\left(  b_{T}\cdot a_{T}\right)  \cdot v_{T}
   =n_{\lambda}\cdot v_{T}$. (It would satisfy the equation if it was true that
   any permutations $p_{1},p_{2}\in R\left(  T\right)  $ and $q_{1},q_{2}\in
   C\left(  T\right)  $ satisfying $p_{1}q_{1}p_{2}q_{2}=1$ would satisfy
   $\operatorname*{sgn}\left(  q_{1}\right)  =\operatorname*{sgn}\left(
   q_{2}\right)  $. But this fails when $n=8$ and $\lambda = \left(  3,3,2\right)  $ and $T=
   \begin{array}
   [c]{ccc}
   1 & 2 & 3\\
   4 & 5 & 6\\
   7 & 8 &
   \end{array}
   $ and $p_{1}=\left[  23164578\right]  $ and $q_{1}=\left[  48372615\right]  $
   and $p_{2}=\left[  32146587\right]  $ and $q_{2}=\left[  18675342\right]  $,
   where all permutations are given in one-line notation. Maybe it holds for
   two-row partitions? I don't know.)

Unfortunately, this is not easy to fix. We can make the equations $\left(
b_{T}\cdot a_{T}\right)  \cdot v_{T}=n_{\lambda}\cdot v_{T}$ and $\left(
a_{T}\cdot b_{T}\right)  \cdot\widetilde{v}_{T}=n_{\lambda}\cdot
\widetilde{v}_{T}$ true if we replace the number $n_{\lambda}$ by
\begin{align*}
n_{\lambda}^{\prime}:=\sum_{\substack{\left(  p_{1},q_{1},p_{2},q_{2}\right)
;\\p_{i}\in R\left(  T\right)  ,\ q_{i}\in C\left(  T\right)  ;\\
p_1q_{1}p_{2}q_{2}=1}}\operatorname*{sgn}\left(  q_{1}\right)  \cdot
\operatorname*{sgn}\left(  q_{2}\right)  .
\end{align*}
But we also need to show that this number $n_{\lambda}^{\prime}$ is positive,
and this is not as obvious as it was for $n_{\lambda}$. Fortunately, this can
still be shown using some easily accessible results: The number $n_{\lambda
}^{\prime}$ is easily seen to be coefficient of the identity permutation $1$
in $\left(  a_{T}b_{T}\right)  ^{2}=c_{T}^{2}$, where $c_T := a_T b_T$ (this differs a bit from Fulton's $c_T$, which is $b_T a_T$, but this is not a major distinction). However, it is known (see,
e.g., Lemma 5.13.3 in [Pavel Etingof et al., *Introduction to representation
theory*, AMS 2011](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/books.html)) that
$c_{T}^{2}=\dfrac{n!}{\left\vert P_{\lambda}\right\vert \left\vert Q_{\lambda
}\right\vert \dim V_{\lambda}}c_{T}$ for a certain positive number $\dfrac
{n!}{\left\vert P_{\lambda}\right\vert \left\vert Q_{\lambda}\right\vert \dim
V_{\lambda}}$ (see loc. cit. for its definition). (Note that the lemma is
stated not for an arbitrary numbering $T$ but only for the specific numbering
$T_{\lambda}$ which has the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ filled in from top to
bottom, row by row. But this is fine, since the numbering can be chosen
arbitrarily.) Furthermore, it is easy to see that the coefficient of the
permutation $1$ in $c_{T}$ is $1$. Hence, the coefficient of $1$ in
$c_{T}^{2}=\dfrac{n!}{\left\vert P_{\lambda}\right\vert \left\vert Q_{\lambda
}\right\vert \dim V_{\lambda}}c_{T}$ is $\dfrac{n!}{\left\vert P_{\lambda
}\right\vert \left\vert Q_{\lambda}\right\vert \dim V_{\lambda}}$, which is
positive. Thus, $n_{\lambda}^{\prime}$ is positive, qed.

2. **page 108, proof of Lemma 2 (§ 8.1):** I am not convinced that "In the
   latter case, fixing $v_{p}=w_{1}$, it suffices to show that the difference of
   the two sides is an alternating function of $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{p},w_{2}$".
   The problem is that the left hand side is not linear in $v_{p}=w_{1}$, since
   $v_{p}$ appears twice in it (once as $v_{p}$ and once again as $w_{1}$). I
   don't know how easy this is to correct, but there are other proofs of Lemma 2
   around in the literature (e.g., it is Exercise 6.66 in
   [arXiv:2008.09862v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09862v3), where it is proved
   just using multi-column Laplace expansion).
3. **page 113, proof of Lemma 4 (§ 8.2):** The claim that "$e_{T^{\prime}}$
   occurs in $g\cdot e_{T}$ with coefficient $1$" is not obvious. More
   importantly, this argument only rules out other highest weight vectors of the
   form $e_{T}$, but not highest weight vectors that are arbitrary linear
   combinations of different $e_{T}$'s. I don't know if this gap can be easily fixed.
   See an answer below for a correct (I hope...) proof of Lemma 4.
4. **page 118, proof of Proposition 1 (§ 8.3):** This proof makes a leap of
   faith in the last paragraph: How exactly does the construction of the map from
   $E^{\lambda}$ to $E\left(  S^{\lambda}\right)  $ yield that $E^{\lambda}\cong
   E\left(  \widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  /E\left(  Q^{\lambda}\right)  $ ?
   There is no direct way to obtain this from the map itself, since it is not
   obvious that the map is injective. Instead, I suggest the following argument:

Proposition 4 in § 7.4 yields that $S^{\lambda}\cong\widetilde{M}^{\lambda
}/Q^{\lambda}$, where $Q^{\lambda}$ is as defined in § 7.4. On the other
hand, set $\mu=\widetilde{\lambda}$ and $\ell=\lambda_{1}$. Then, (11) shows
that there is an isomorphism
\begin{align*}
H:E\left(  \widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  \rightarrow\wedge^{\mu_{1}}\left(
E\right)  \otimes\cdots\otimes\wedge^{\mu_{\ell}}\left(  E\right)
\end{align*}
(which sends any pure tensor $\left(  v_{1}\otimes v_{2}\otimes\cdots\otimes
v_{n}\right)  \otimes_{\mathbb{C}\left[  S_{n}\right]  }\left[  T\right]  \in
E\left(  M^{\lambda}\right)  $ to
\begin{align*}
\left(  v_{T\left(  1,1\right)  }\wedge v_{T\left(  1,2\right)  }\wedge
\cdots\wedge v_{T\left(  1,\mu_{1}\right)  }\right)  \otimes\cdots
\otimes\left(  v_{T\left(  \ell,1\right)  }\wedge v_{T\left(  \ell,2\right)
}\wedge\cdots\wedge v_{T\left(  \ell,\mu_{\ell}\right)  }\right)
\end{align*}
).

However, the inclusion $Q^{\lambda}\rightarrow\widetilde{M}^{\lambda}$ yields
(by the functoriality of $E$) a map from $E\left(  Q^{\lambda}\right)  $ to
$E\left(  \widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  $. Due to how $Q^{\lambda}$ was
defined, the image of this map is the span of all the differences
$\mathbf{v}\left(  T\right)  \otimes v_{T}-\sum_{S}\mathbf{v}\left(  S\right)
\otimes v_{S}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ ranges over all pure tensors in $E^{\otimes
n}$, where $T$ varies over all numberings of $\lambda$, where $j$ and $k$ vary
over all integers satisfying $1\leq j\leq\ell-1$ and $1\leq k\leq\mu_{j+1}$,
and where the sum is over all numberings $S$ in $\pi_{j,k}\left(  T\right)  $.
Under our above isomorphism $H$, these differences $\mathbf{v}\left(
T\right)  \otimes v_{T}-\sum_{S}\mathbf{v}\left(  S\right)  \otimes v_{S}$
turn into exactly the generators $\wedge\mathbf{v}-\sum\wedge\mathbf{w}$ of
the subspace $Q^{\lambda}\left(  E\right)  $ defined in § 8.1. Hence, under
the isomorphism $H$, the image of $E\left(  Q^{\lambda}\right)  $ in $E\left(
\widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  $ becomes the subspace $Q^{\lambda}\left(
E\right)  $. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E\left(  \widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  /E\left(  Q^{\lambda}\right)
\cong\left(  \wedge^{\mu_{1}}\left(  E\right)  \otimes\cdots\otimes\wedge
^{\mu_{\ell}}\left(  E\right)  \right)  /Q^{\lambda}\left(  E\right)
=E^{\lambda}
\end{align*}
(by (4)).

But the functor $E$ is right-exact (since it is a tensor functor), and thus we
have $E\left(  \widetilde{M}^{\lambda}/Q^{\lambda}\right)  \cong E\left(
\widetilde{M}^{\lambda}\right)  /E\left(  Q^{\lambda}\right)  \cong
E^{\lambda}$. In other words, $E\left(  S^{\lambda}\right)  \cong E^{\lambda}$
(since $S^{\lambda}\cong\widetilde{M}^{\lambda}/Q^{\lambda}$). This proves
Proposition 1.

**Typos:**

1. **page 73, proof of Proposition 1 (§ 6.1):** In the last identity, replace $\prod_{i=1}^m\left(1-x_jt\right)$ by $\prod_{i=1}^m\left(1-x_it\right)$.
2. **page 91, proof of Theorem (§ 7.3):** On line 4 of the proof, replace $M^{\left(\lambda\right)}$ by $M^\lambda$.
3. **page 94, proof of Proposition 3 (§ 7.3):** Three missing $)$ parentheses.
4. **page 94, Exercise 11 (§ 7.3):** Replace "$\mathbb{C}_{n}$" by
   "$\mathbb{C}^{n}$".
5. **page 95, middle of the page (§ 7.4):** "subspace generated by all $\left[T\right] - \operatorname{sgn}\left(q\right)\left[T\right]$" should be "subspace generated by all $\left[qT\right] - \operatorname{sgn}\left(q\right)\left[T\right]$".
6. **page 101, proof of Proposition 4 (§ 7.4):** The last sum ($\sum_{\ell=0}^k \left(-1\right)^\ell \dbinom{k}{\ell}$) should actually be $\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-m} \left(-1\right)^\ell \dbinom{k-m}{\ell}$. (Of course, this still equals $0$.)
7. **page 103, Exercise 21 (§ 7.4):** The sum $\sum_{\lambda, \nu}$ should actually be a sum $\sum_{\lambda, \mu}$.
8. **page 111, Exercise 2 (§ 8.1):** Of course, in (iii), the partition $\lambda$ should be assumed to be nonempty.
9. **page 111, paragraph between Exercises 2 and 3 (§ 8.1):** "a left action of the algebra $\operatorname{End}_R\left(E\right)$ on $E^\lambda$" should be "a left action of the multiplicative monoid $\operatorname{End}_R\left(E\right)$ on $E^\lambda$" (since this action is not linear in the acting element: i.e., two endomorphisms $U, V \in \operatorname{End}_R\left(E\right)$ will rarely satisfy $\left(U+V\right)\mathbf{e} = U\mathbf{e} + V\mathbf{e}$ for all $\mathbf{e} \in E^\lambda$).
   Likewise, the "$M_mR$" has to be understood as a multiplicative monoid, not as an algebra. Similarly, just below Exercise 3, "The algebra $M_mR$ also acts on the left on the $R$-algebra $R\left[Z\right]$" should be read as "The monoid $M_mR$ also acts by $R$-algebra endomorphisms on the left on the $R$-algebra $R\left[Z\right]$".
10. **page 114, middle of the page (§ 8.2):** "if and only if $\lambda
    _{i}+k=\lambda_{i}+k^{\prime}$ for all $i$" should be "if and only if
    $\lambda_{i}+k=\lambda_{i}^{\prime}+k^{\prime}$ for all $i$".
11. **page 118, proof of Proposition 1 (§ 8.3):** The $\lambda$ in "$E\left(S_\lambda\right)$" should be a superscript, not a subscript.
12. **page 123, line -8 (§ 8.3):** Replace "presentation" by "representation".
13. **page 125, generators of $Q$ (§ 8.4):** Both $w_p$s in the formula should be $w_q$s.
14. **page 133, Exercise 1 (§ 9.1):** The $i_{d+1}$ subscript should be $j_{d+1}$.
15. **page 133, proof of Lemma 1 (§ 9.1):** "Fix some $i_i, \ldots, i_d$" should be "Fix some $i_1, \ldots, i_d$", of course.

Comment: A noble endeavor, but I'm afraid this isn't a question and as such isn't appropriate for MO.

Comment: I hope this question stays open. Other errata questions have clearly been found useful, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42241/errata-for-atiyah-macdonald

Comment: About errata 3: I agree this is a serious gap in the proof. In a joint paper with deBoeck and Paget we needed a construction like Fulton's and went to some trouble to fix the mistake: see Proposition 2.14 and the previous comment on the 'main novel feature' in https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03448.

Comment: From time to time, there arises some discussion about the possibility of an [errata database](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3038/). Unfortunately, at this time, there appears to be no satisfactory solution to this perennial problem.

Comment: If I ever write a book, I would be so happy to have someone read it this carefully.

Comment: @JimConant: If you ever write a book on representations of symmetric groups (characteristic-free in particular), I'd love to see it!

Comment: @MarkWildon: See my answer below for a characteristic-free way to prove Proposition 1, provided that the triangular matrix can come from a ring extension (this caveat is relevant only for finite fields). This is similar to what you are doing, but I am comparing leading coefficients rather than $t^1$-coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correct (I hope) proof of Lemma 4 in § 8.2 (inspired by § 5.3 in
[Desarmenien/Kung/Rota 1978](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/dkr1978.pdf)):

Given an integer $1<k\leq m$ and a column $c$ of some tableau, we say that $c$
is **$k$-defective** if $c$ contains $k$ but not $k-1$. We also say that a
column of a tableau is **defective** if it is $k$-defective for at least one
$1<k\leq m$. It is easy to see that any non-defective column must have exactly
the entries $1,2,\ldots,i$ (from top to bottom) for some $0\leq i\leq m$.
Hence, the only tableau on $\lambda$ that has no defective columns is the
tableau $U\left(  \lambda\right)  $. Hence, each tableau $T\neq U\left(
\lambda\right)  $ on $\lambda$ has at least one $k$-defective column for at
least one $1<k\leq m$.

Let $w\in E^{\lambda}$ be a highest weight vector. We must show that $w$ is a
scalar multiple of $e_{U\left(  \lambda\right)  }$.

Assume the contrary. Write $w$ in the form $w=\sum_{T}w_{T}e_{T}$, where $T$
varies over the tableaux on $\lambda$, and where the $w_{T}$ are coefficients
in $\mathbb{C}$. This expression is unique by Theorem 1 in § 8.1.

We let $\mathfrak{T}$ be the set of all tableaux $T$ on $\lambda$ satisfying
$w_{T}\neq0$. Thus, we can rewrite $w=\sum_{T}w_{T}e_{T}$ as $w=\sum
_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}$.

Hence, at least one $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ is distinct from $U\left(
\lambda\right)  $ (since $w$ is not a scalar multiple of $e_{U\left(
\lambda\right)  }$). Thus, there exists at least one $1<k\leq m$ such that at
least one tableau $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ has a $k$-defective column (since each
tableau $T\neq U\left(  \lambda\right)  $ on $\lambda$ has at least one
$k$-defective column for at least one $1<k\leq m$). Choose the **smallest**
such $k$. Thus,
\begin{equation}
\text{no tableau }T\in\mathfrak{T}\text{ has a }p\text{-defective column for
any }1<p<k.
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.0}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Moreover, let $i$ be the maximum number of $k$-defective columns that a
tableau $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ can have. Then, $i>0$ (since at least one tableau
$T\in\mathfrak{T}$ has a $k$-defective column).

Now, let $t\in\mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary, and consider the upper triangular
matrix $M:=I_{m}+tE_{k-1,k}\in B$, where $E_{p,q}$ is the elementary matrix
with a $1$ in the $\left(  p,q\right)  $-th cell and zeroes everywhere else.
The action of this matrix $M$ on $E$ transforms $e_{k}$ into $e_{k}+te_{k-1}$,
while leaving all other basis vectors $e_{j}$ invariant.

But $M\in B$ and thus $Mw\in Bw=\mathbb{C}^{\ast}w$ (since $w$ is a highest
weight vector). In other words, $Mw=\rho w$ for some $\rho\in\mathbb{C}^{\ast
}$. Consider this $\rho$. We have $Mw=\rho w$. In view of $w=\sum
_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}$, we can rewrite this as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}Me_{T}=\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}\rho w_{T}
e_{T}.
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.1}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Let $T$ be a tableau on $\lambda$. Let $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $
denote the result of replacing each entry $k$ of $T$ by a $k-1$, except for
those $k$'s that already have a $k-1$ in their column. For example, if $k=3$
and $T=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$, then $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$. It is easy to see that $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ is again a
tableau. (Indeed, the entries of $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ clearly
increase strictly in each column. To see that they increase weakly in each
row, argue that the only thing that could go wrong would be a $k$ standing
left of a $k-1$ in some row; but then the $k-1$ would have to come from a $k$
that got replaced by a $k-1$, but this would mean that the former $k$ has a
$k-1$ in its column in $T$ but the latter $k$ does not, which easily violates
the weakly-increasing property of the preceding row of $T$.)

Hence, if we recall how $e_{T}$ was defined (just before Lemma 1 in § 8.1),
then we see that $Me_{T}$ is obtained from $e_{T}$ by replacing each $e_{k}$
(corresponding to a $k$ in $T$) by $e_{k}+te_{k-1}$. We can imagine this
replacement happening gradually, column by column. When we replace a $k$ by
$k-1$ in a given column of $T$, one of two things can happen: Either the $k$
that we replace already has a $k-1$ in its column (we call this a
"non-defective $k$"), or it does not (we call this a "defective $k$"). In the
former case, the replacement falls flat (i.e., changes nothing) (because
$e_{k-1}\wedge\left(  e_{k}+te_{k-1}\right)  =e_{k-1}\wedge e_{k}$, so that
the value of $e_{T}$ does not change when we replace that particular $e_{k}$
by $e_{k}+te_{k-1}$). In the latter case, $e_{k}$ becomes $e_{k}+te_{k-1}$,
and upon expanding the tensor in $E^{\lambda}$ we obtain two addends, one of
which is the one we had before our replacement while the other has an extra
$t$ factor. At the end of our gradual replacement procedure, $e_{T}$ has
become a sum of $2^{j\left(  T\right)  }$ addends of the form $e_{S}t^{s}$
(with $S$ being a filling, not always a tableau), where $j\left(  T\right)  $
is the total number of $k$-defective columns of $T$ (that is, the total number
of defective $k$'s). Hence, expanding $Me_{T}$ as a polynomial in $t$, we find
\begin{equation}
Me_{T}=e_{T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  }t^{j\left(  T\right)  }+\left(
\text{some terms of the form }e_{S}t^{s}\text{ with }0<s<j\left(  T\right)
\right)  +e_{T}
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.2}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
(the highest power of $t$ comes from replacing every defective $k$ by $k-1$,
whereas the constant term comes from replacing nothing). Note that the
fillings $S$ on the right hand side are not always tableaux, but they all have
fewer $k$'s than $T$ does, and therefore they can be written as linear
combinations of $e_{Q}$'s for tableaux $Q$ that have fewer $k$'s than $T$ does
(indeed, the first paragraph in the proof of Theorem 1 in § 8.1 explains
how to rewrite $e_{S}$ for a filling $S$ as a linear combination of $e_{Q}$'s
for tableaux $Q$, and it is easy to see that the latter $Q$'s have the same
number of $k$'s as $S$).

Forget that we fixed $T$. Using the equation \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.2}, which
we just showed for each tableau $T$ on $\lambda$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}Me_{T}\\
& =\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}\left(  e_{T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]
}t^{j\left(  T\right)  }+\left(  \text{some terms of the form }e_{S}
t^{s}\text{ with }0<s<j\left(  T\right)  \right)  +e_{T}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}\text{ with }j\left(  T\right)  =i}w_{T}e_{T\left[
k\rightarrow k-1\right]  }t^{i}+\left(  \text{some terms of the form }
e_{S}t^{s}\text{ with }0<s<i\right)  \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}
\end{align*}
(since the maximum $j\left(  T\right)  $ for a $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ is $i$ (by
the definition of $i$)). In view of \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.1}, we can rewrite
this as
\begin{align}
\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}\rho w_{T}e_{T}  & =\underbrace{\sum_{T\in
\mathfrak{T}\text{ with }j\left(  T\right)  =i}w_{T}e_{T\left[  k\rightarrow
k-1\right]  }t^{i}+\left(  \text{some terms of the form }e_{S}t^{s}\text{ with
}0<s<i\right)  }_{\text{we call these terms the "error terms"}}\nonumber\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}
.
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.4}
\tag{4}
\end{align}

Recall that the $e_{T}$'s for all tableaux $T$ on $\lambda$ are linearly
independent (by Theorem 1 in § 8.1). Hence, comparing coefficients in front
of $e_{T}$ for a strategically chosen $T$ (namely, some tableau $T\in
\mathfrak{T}$ with the largest number of $k$'s in it), we conclude from
\eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.4} that $\rho=1$ (because this $T$ only appears in the
sum on the left hand side and in the very last sum on the right hand side, but
not among the "error terms", because the $S$'s in the error terms have fewer
$k$'s than $T$ does). Hence, \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.4} rewrites as
\begin{align}
\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}  & =\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}\text{ with
}j\left(  T\right)  =i}w_{T}e_{T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  }
t^{i}+\left(  \text{some terms of the form }e_{S}t^{s}\text{ with
}0<s<i\right)  \nonumber\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}}w_{T}e_{T}
.
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.5}
\tag{5}
\end{align}

Now, forget that we fixed $t$. We thus have proved the equality
\eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.5} for each $t\in\mathbb{C}$. But
\eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.5} is a polynomial identity in $t$ (with coefficients in
$E^{\lambda}$), and thus must hold as a formal equality between polynomials if
it holds for each $t\in\mathbb{C}$ (since $\mathbb{C}$ is an infinite field).
Hence, we can compare coefficients in \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.5}. In particular,
comparing coefficients in front of $t^{i}$, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
0=\sum_{T\in\mathfrak{T}\text{ with }j\left(  T\right)  =i}w_{T}e_{T\left[
k\rightarrow k-1\right]  }
\label{eq.darij1.lem4.6}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
(since $i>0$). Note that there exists at least one $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ with
$j\left(  T\right)  =i$ (by the definition of $i$), so that the sum on the
right hand side of \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.6} is nonempty.

But the $e_{S}$ for different tableaux $S$ on $\lambda$ are linearly
independent (by Theorem 1 in § 8.1). Thus, the equality
\eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.6} is only possible if there exist two different
$T\in\mathfrak{T}$ with $j\left(  T\right)  =i$ that have the same $T\left[
k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ (since the sum on the right hand side of
\eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.6} is nonempty, and all coefficients $w_{T}$ are nonzero
by the definition of $\mathfrak{T}$). So this must be the case. In other
words, there exist two distinct tableaux $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ in $\mathfrak{T}$
with $j\left(  T_{1}\right)  =j\left(  T_{2}\right)  =i$ and $T_{1}\left[
k\rightarrow k-1\right]  =T_{2}\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $.

But I claim that such $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ in $\mathfrak{T}$ cannot exist. In
other words, I claim that any $T\in\mathfrak{T}$ with $j\left(  T\right)  =i$
can be uniquely reconstructed from $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $. How?
Let me show:

Recall that $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ is constructed from $T$ by
replacing all $i$ "defective" $k$'s by $k-1$'s. Thus, we could reconstruct $T$
from $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ by replacing them back, if we knew
which of the $k-1$'s in $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ are coming from
$k$'s in $T$. Let us try to find them.

Any entry $k-1$ in $T$ must have the entries $1,2,\ldots,k-2$ above it (since
otherwise, its column would be $p$-defective for some $1<p<k$, but this would
contradict \eqref{eq.darij1.lem4.0}), and thus must lie in the $\left(
k-1\right)  $-st row. In other words, any entry of $T$ that does not lie in
the $\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row cannot be a $k-1$.

Hence, any entry $k-1$ in $T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ that does not
lie in the $\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row cannot come from a $k-1$ in $T$, but
must have come from a $k$ in $T$ that was replaced by a $k-1$. Thus, in order
to reconstruct $T$, we must replace any such $k-1$ back by $k$.

It remains to figure out what to do with the $k-1$'s in $T\left[  k\rightarrow
k-1\right]  $ that do lie in the $\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row: Which of them
should we replace back by $k$'s and which should we leave as they are?
Fortunately, we know **how many** of them we should replace: We have obtained
$T\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  $ from $T$ by replacing $j\left(  T\right)
=i$ many $k$'s by $k-1$'s, and thus we must (in turn) replace $i$ many $k-1$'s
by $k$'s to reconstruct $T$. Let $s$ be the number of other $k-1$'s that we
have already replaced back by $k$'s (these are the ones that do not lie in the
$\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row). Then, we still need to replace $i-s$ many
$k-1$'s in the $\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row back by $k$'s. Since our goal is
to obtain a tableau (because $T$ is a tableau), these $i-s$ many $k-1$'s must
be the rightmost $k-1$'s in that row. Thus, we replace the rightmost $i-s$
many $k-1$'s in the $\left(  k-1\right)  $-st row by $k$'s. At that point, we
have reconstructed $T$.

As explained, this shows that two distinct tableaux $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ in
$\mathfrak{T}$ with $j\left(  T_{1}\right)  =j\left(  T_{2}\right)  =i$ and
$T_{1}\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]  =T_{2}\left[  k\rightarrow k-1\right]
$ cannot exist. This contradicts their existence that was proved before, and
so the proof is complete.